# didRefreshRegistrationToken is not being called if user Don't Allow notifications swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

My problem is not being solved after I've tried a lot of questions which might have the solution for this issue:

I want to get `FCM Token`. In `AppDelegate.swift` I've imported

```
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
```

After that I've extended it with `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate` and then in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I've added:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()
```

And after that I've added these four functions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Here")
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
```

Now the issue is when I run the app it shows the alert which ask for permissions for sending notification. Allowing it or disallowing it is not my concern I have implemented `MessagingDelegate` method `didRefreshRegistrationToken` so it should be called, but it is not calling that method. So am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an Observer like that

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

And add this method in your Appdelegate like that

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-generation) you can either:

1. supply a delegate conforming to the `FIRMessagingDelegate` protocol
2. listen for an NSNotification named `kFIRMessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshNotification`

If you take the first option, you need to set the delegate

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

You can see this done in the [quickstart example code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L34)